# How can I pass variable from the onclick of a button to the javascript code?

Tags: javascript, php, forms

This code works:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit_form()
{
    if(confirm('My message here.'))
    {
        document.my_form_name.submit();
    }
}
</script>

<form action="index.php" method="post" name="my_form_name">

<input type="button" value="Skip" onclick="submit_form()">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save and continue">

</form>
```

HIGHLIGHTS:

**function submit_form()**

document.**my_form_name**.submit()

form action="index.php" method="post" name="**my_form_name**"

input type="button" value="Skip" **onclick="submit_form()**"

---

This does not work (but I want it to):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submit_form(variable)
{
    if(confirm('My message here.'))
    {
        document.variable.submit();
    }
}
</script>

<form action="index.php" method="post" name="my_form_name">

<input type="button" value="Skip" onclick="submit_form('my_form_name')">
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save and continue">

</form>
```

HIGHLIGHTS:

**function submit_form(variable)**

document.**variable**.submit()

form action="index.php" method="post" name="**my_form_name**"

input type="button" value="Skip" **onclick="submit_form('my_form_name')**"

---

I'm quite ok with PHP but lack decent JavaScript knowledge so if someone could point me in the right direction I'd be very happy!

And why do I need 2 buttons? Well, I want to display the skip-button to the left of the continue-button (first in HTML flow) but I do not want it to be default action if form is submitted by pressing enter key, therefore I let skip-button be "just" a button (controlled by JavaScript for submitting) and only the continue-button to be a "real" submit-button...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `document.variable`, it looks for something named `variable`. If you want it to look for the variable's value (`'my_form_name'`), use `document[variable]`:

```
if(confirm('My message here.'))
{
    document[variable].submit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Blex has provided the right answer. Even though I am not a fan of inline JS, the following can save some typing and improve readability of your code:

HTML:

```
 <input type="button" value="Skip" onclick="submit_form(this)">
 <!-- use this instead of 'my_form_name' -->
```

JS:

```
 variable.form.submit(); //instead of document[variable].submit();
```